Matlab Ramp Source and Simulation Time
I am using Matlab and Simulink to simulate the behavioral function of an ADC.
I applied a ramp input to this ADC using "Ramp" in Simulink and ran the simulation. This is what I noticed from tout (in Workspace).
Without applying the ramp input, tout should be every sampling period (8ns) as shown below:

After applying the ramp input, some extra time points (in this case two extra points) unrelated to the sampling period (8ns) were added at the onset of the ramp input (ramp applied at 80ns), as shown in the highlighted region below:

I'm not sure why this happened. Could you please give me an indicator?
Thank you very much
